# Who was telling secret of Chakravyuha to Subhadra? Krishna or Arjuna?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, arjuna, subhadra

There seems to be a confusion (may be, because of lack of citation so far), about who was telling the secret of Chakravyuha to Subhadra? Krishna or Arjuna!

I was going through [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2365/was-abhimanyus-death-a-plot?rq=1) question, and came across different views about who was telling the secret of Chakravyuha to Subhadra. Was it Krishna or Arjuna? It seems both views didn't give citations to support their claim.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is possible that either Shri Krishna or Arjuna told about Chakravyuha to Subhadra because Subhadra had stayed both with Arjuna and Shri Kirshna at different times during his pregnancy period and both Krishna and Arjuna knew about Chakravyuha.

But having said that, it is Abhimanyu who makes it clear from whom he learned that specific art of war. Seeing the Chakravyuha arrangement Yudhisthira says to Abhimanyu:

> तवं वार्जुनॊ वा कृष्णॊ वा भिन्द्यात परद्युम्न एव वा
>    चक्रव्यूहं महाबाहॊ पञ्चमॊ ऽनयॊ न विद्यते [MB - 7.34.15]
>
> **Meaning**
>   Thyself, or Arjuna or Krishna, or Pradyumna, can pierce that array. O mighty-armed one, no fifth person can be found (to achieve that teat).

Then in reply Abhimanyu says:

> दरॊणस्य दृढम अव्यग्रम अनीक परवरं युधि
>    पितॄणां जयम आकाङ्क्षन्न अवगाहे भिनद्मि च
>    उपदिष्टॊ हि मे पित्रा यॊगॊ ऽनीकस्य भेदने
>    नॊत्सहे तु विनिर्गन्तुम अहं कस्यां चिद आपदि   [MB - 7.34.18,19]
>
> **Meaning**
>   Abhimanyu said, 'Desiring victory to my sires, soon shall I in battle penetrate into that firm, fierce and foremost of arrays formed by Drona. **I have been taught by my father** the method of (penetrating and) smiting this kind of array. I shall not be able, however, to come out if any kind of danger overtakes me

So from the words of Abhimanyu it is clear that it was Arjuna from whom he learned the secret.

Answer (score 0):

It has to be Krishna, because when the Pandavas were exiled to the forests Subhadra is taken back to Dwarka by Balarama in the pretext so as to alleviate the stress on the already struggling Pandavas. But the truth is she is pregnant and Balarama did not permit her being in such harsh conditions. Balarama finds it sole purpose to avoid forest exiles in this avatar. Subadra was with Krishna when she was pregnant.

Also Arjuna never sees Abhimanyu till he is fully grown when he returns from hiding in Viratnagar. It is during this period Abhimanyu grows under the guidance of Krishna, who is also his guru.

Comment: But to be sure, we need proper citation to support the claim!